# Soft keyboard hides popup window

Tags: android-view, android-keypad, android-popupwindow

I had used emoji library in my app. Most of the devices its working perfectly, but in some devices unable to show emoji popup window at the bottom of the screen. The device soft input keyboard fully hides the emoji popup in bottom of the screen.

Comment: So are you asking how to handle displaying the pop up and the keyboard, or how to hide the keyboard?

Comment: yes. i need to display both of controls at bottom position. its not working only some of the devices, not for all